# Convergence in limit implies almost sure convergence?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, convergence

Consider two sequences of real valued random variables $\{X_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{Y_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, with, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $X_n$ and $Y_n$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P), $ respectively with support $\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y}$. Consider a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$.

Assume that for some $b\in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} | \overbrace{P(X_n\leq b| Y_n=y)|}^{\text{scalar}}-a_n|=0 \text{ }\text{ $\forall y \in \mathcal{Y}$}
$$

Does this imply 
$$
|\overbrace{P(X_n\leq b| Y_n)}^{\text{Random variable because of $Y_n$ (unless $X_n\perp Y_n$)}}-a_n| \rightarrow_{a.s.}0 \text{ as $n\rightarrow \infty$}
$$
or equivalently
$$
\Big(P(X_n\leq b| Y_n)-a_n\Big) \rightarrow_{a.s.}0 \text{ as $n\rightarrow \infty$}
$$
or equivalently
$$
P(X_n\leq b| Y_n) \rightarrow_{a.s.}a_n \text{ as $n\rightarrow \infty$}
$$
?

Comment: What would it even mean for a probability to converge almost surely, or for a sequence indexed on $n$ to converge to $a_n$?